# Correo desde PHP llega como spam

Tags: php, email, smtp

Buen dia,

En el siguiente codigo PHP envío dos correos, solo les dejo la parte del envío ya que la parte superior donde se declaran las variables tengo todo bien,

Primer envio:

debo enviarlo a un @gmail.com que siempre es el mismo al cual llega sin problemas

Segundo envio:

el problema es el segundo envio el cual el usuario digita su correo electronico, llega como spam bien sea a gmail o hotmail, hice la prueba a un @dominio.com el cual dicha cuenta esta en cPanel con Hostgator y si llega bien, en resumidas cuentas es a hotmail o gmail

//de aqui hacia arriba declaré variables de acuerdo a ciertas cosas

//PRIMER ENVÍO, funciona bien

```
    $para='bpguribe@gmail.com';
    $titulo    = 'Nueva solicitud de revision tecnica '.$nuevo_id;
    $mensaje   = 'Se ha recibido una nueva solicitud de instalacion de gas, numero : '.$nuevo_id."\r\n"."\r\n".

    'DATOS DEL SOLICITANTE:'."\r\n".
    'Nombre: '.$nombre."\r\n".
    'Celular: '.$celular."\r\n".
    'Direccion: '.$direccion."\r\n".
    'Comentarios: '.$comentarios."\r\n".
    'e-mail: '.$correo."\r\n"."\r\n".

    'DATOS ADJUNTOS:'."\r\n"."\r\n".
    'Foto1: '.$ruta_final_foto1."\r\n"."\r\n".
    'Foto2: '.$ruta_final_foto2."\r\n"."\r\n";

    $cabeceras = 'From: solicitudgas@tecflucol.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$correo . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

//SEGUNDO ENVÍO, LLEGA COMO SPAM A GMAIL O HOTMAIL, intenté con uno distinto funcionando en cPanel con Hostgator y si llega bien

```
    $para2 = $correo;
    $titulo2    = 'Confirmacion solicitud tecnica numero '.$nuevo_id;
    $mensaje2   = 'Has realizado una solicitud de revision tecnica de gas para su hogar, con numero : '.$nuevo_id."\r\n"."\r\n".
    'Le estaremos contactando al numero proporcionado: '.$celular."\r\n".
    'Gracias por usar nuestros servicios'."\r\n".
    'Cordialmente:'."\r\n".
    'Tecflucol';

    $cabeceras2 = 'From: comercial@tecflucol.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: comercial@tecflucol.com'. "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($para2, $titulo2, $mensaje2, $cabeceras2);
```

Comment: Ohhh, cuál código?

Comment: Yo diría que no intentes hacer que no llegue como spam por programación. Por que la verdad no creo que se pueda. Ya depende de los servidores como gmail o hotmail. Ya que al detectar que estas enviando correo a personas que nunca habias enviado, otro factor puede ser que te hallan marcado algunos correos como spam.

Comment: en gmail ve al mensaje y a la derecha del título debe haber una flecha para mostrar opciones, elige "ver original/show original" ahi te muestra toda la ruta que hizo el mail hasta la casilla. si en alguno o varios de los pasos el dominio del sender/relay no coincide con el dominio del sender (la direccion de email de quien envía) lo mas seguro es que sea marcado como spam, un salto puede zafar ya dos no

Comment: @aloMalbarez me muestra lo siguiente... puedes decirme donde encuentro lo que dices? y de ser asi como dices, que podria hacer en mi codigo?

Comment: no me deja pegar tanto codigo :( queria mostrarte lo que sale

Comment: tener en cuenta que en el caso de enviar a un email de hostgator, si el script tambien esta en hostgator el mail no sale a internet , es entregado internamente

Comment: la pauta mas clara es si en las cabeceras hay algo que diga `smtp.mailfrom=USUARIO@DOMINIO`  y sólo  `USUARIO` es igual a la direccion de correo que envía, por ejemplo un spam que tengo aca se recibio como de `@rcentral517.webserversystems.com`

Comment: como solución para un servidor compartido es usar una libreria de mail y una cuenta de email via smtp https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Te voy a ser honesto. Anteriormente yo tenía un problema similar y decidí enviar correos con la librería PHPMailer, además de que es más fácil crear las estructuras desde entonces no he tenido ningún problema:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial Aunque, el mandar un mail a la carpeta de SPAM tiene mucho que ver también con el servidor que recibe el correo.

Comment: hay sitios que te permiten ver el score de tu email, y te dicen que elementos juegan en contra, por ejemplo `https://spamscorechecker.com/`

Comment: Creo que el problema no es la programación, si no como lo recibe el servidor, quiza si agregas algún certificado o firma digital valida, en cualquier caso ya no te lo mandaría al spam.